# How can saliva neutralise acids produced by bacterial cells in our mouth if it is itself acidic in nature?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, saliva

My school textbook makes the following claim:

[image]

This means that saliva must be basic. However, I learnt that the pH value of saliva is about 6.8, which would surely make it acidic. How can the above point be correct then?

Comment: even if an acid is 6.0, it's reaction with other acids depends on the quantity, so a lot of the mild acid can react with an amount of the stronger acid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saliva is neutral, not acidic (6.8 is very barely acidic), and is a means to carry the acid away physically, and is also much less acidic than acid produced by bacteria, so is still effective in neutralizing.

Comment: Also substances with higher pH can act as bases against substances with lower pH. If I remember right, alcohol acts as base when warmed with carboxylic acid in esterification reaction. Enzymes are very sensitive to change in pH so that probably reduces bacterial activity.
 https://youtu.be/UGs0hrIkjss

Comment: Saliva also has anti microbial properties and might kill bacteria or hinder their growth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wound_licking